# How to get multiple values from "return" as in "print"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, return

When I run the code below, I get back only the first result. If I replace `return (a,d)` with `print (a,d)`, I get the full set of results. (I understand that running `print (a,d)` doesn't save the output anywhere.)

What do I need to change to get the full output and not just the first result?

```
nums = [(str(i)) for i in range(100,106)]

def foo(aa):
    for a in nums:
        for b in a :
            c= sum(int(b)**2 for b in a)
            d=''.join(sorted(a,reverse=True))
            if (c>5):
                return(a,d) 


output = foo(nums)
print(output)
```

UPDATE --  I'm expecting the following output:

```
103 310
103 310
103 310
104 410
104 410
104 410
105 510
105 510
105 510
```

The `return(a,d)` gives me just:

```
103 310
```

Comment: `return (a, d)` returns a tuple with two values. It will definitely capture both values. But `print(output)` will not generate the same output as `print(a, d)`

Comment: https://repl.it/@codeguru/VillainousUniqueServers As far as I can tell, this prints "the full set of results". If you run the code in the above link, you get the output `('103', '310')` which looks like both results to me, not just the first one.

Comment: While the questioner is returning multiple values, the question text indicates that they want to return even more; they want to return every value that would be printed if `return` was replaced by `print`. That needs a "use a list/generator" dupe, not a tuple dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are

```
nums = [(str(i)) for i in range(100,106)]

def foo(aa):
    for a in nums:
        for b in a :
            c= sum(int(b)**2 for b in a)
            d=''.join(sorted(a,reverse=True))
            if (c>5):
                return(a,d)


output , output2 = foo(nums)
print(output, output2)
```

EDIT

create a list and insert tuples

```
nums = [(str(i)) for i in range(100,106)]

def foo(aa):
    list_of_numbs = list() # create a list
    for a in nums:
        for b in a :
            c= sum(int(b)**2 for b in a)
            d=''.join(sorted(a,reverse=True))
            if (c>5):
                list_of_numbs.append((a,d)) #insert your desire tuplet in the list
                #print(a,d)
    return list_of_numbs # return the list

x = foo(nums)
print(x) # print the list
# OR
for i,j in x:     
    print(i,j)
```

Comment: Please explain in words a little more about how this solves the problem.

Comment: This worked, thank you! The main thing I had overlooked was putting return at the indented level.

Comment: If you just want to print out a tuple normally without having to write out variables, you can just do this: `value = function()` where function can return any a tuple that could be any size, then you print such tuple like `print(*value)`, it's called tuple unpacking and if `value` is `(a, b, c)`, then `print(*value)` is equivalent to `print(a, b, c)`.